# escape characters using xquery

Tags: xslt, xquery

I am calling a Rest Service from OSB and it returns

```
<ass:description>
WEST RIDE DR & LAKE RIDE DR 444' OF 8\" VC
</ass:description>
```

Rest adapter automatically converst it to

```
<ass:description>
WESTÂ RIDEÂ DRÂ FROMÂ 11652Â TOÂ WESTÂ RIDEÂ DRÂ &amp;Â LAKEÂ RIDEÂ DRÂ 444'Â OFÂ 8" 
</ass:description>
```

i am using a xquery for transformation of the entire response.
i want to write a xquery function for this element to transform it to the original response (remove the escaping of characters)i.e

```
<ass:description>
WEST RIDE DR & LAKE RIDE DR 444' OF 8\" VC
</ass:description>
```

i tried to use replace function and escape uri function. but not sure if i am doing it right

Comment: It looks to me as if those spaces in the original are all non-breaking spaces (0xA0) (or have been converted to non-breaking spaces), which have then been wrongly encoded and decoded. If a non-breaking space is encoded in UTF8, and is then read by software that wrongly thinks it is reading Latin-1, then the character will be turned into the two characters Â  followed by space.